# How many unique vertices in octahedron based sphere approximation

Tags: geometry, 3d

Using a triangular facet approximation of a sphere based on [Sphere Generation by Paul Bourke](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/).

We take an octahedron and bisect the edges of its facets
to form 4 triangles from each triangle.

`/\                  /\                  /\
         /  \                /  \                /__\
        /    \              /    \              /\  /\
       /      \            /______\            /__\/__\
      /        \          /\      /\          /\  /\  /\
     /          \        /  \    /  \        /__\/__\/__\
    /            \      /    \  /    \      /\  /\  /\  /\
   /______________\    /______\/______\    /__\/__\/__\/__\
    0th generation      1st generation      2nd generation`

This happens for every face so 8 times for the first generation.

Between each generation new vertices are pushed to the surface of the sphere.

The number of facets will be $(4^\mathrm{generations}) \cdot 8$

Some facets will share vertices: in the $0^{th}$ generation there are 6 unique vertices (it's an octahedron).

How many unique vertices will there be in the $N^{th}$ generation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the Euler characteristic formula
$$V-E+F = 2.$$

You've already calculated that $F=8\cdot 4^N$. You also know that all of the facets are triangles; that means that each triangle has three half-edges or $3F=2E$. That means
$$2V - F = 4$$
or
$$V = 2 + 4^{N+1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that each vertex is shared by $6$ faces, except the six vertices of the original octahedron, which are always shared by only $4$ faces in each generation.  Each face has $3$ vertices.  The number of faces in generation $N$ is $8 \cdot 4^{N}$.  Putting this together, we see that the number of vertices in that generation is $$\frac{3 \cdot 8 \cdot 4^{N} - 4 \cdot 6}{6} + 6 = 4^{N+1} + 2$$